# In a C# Windows Runtime Component, how can I warn developers not to use == with a public class?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, c#-5.0

In writing a C# Metro DLL that's being **output to WinMD format**, I have a public class `Id`. Although it overrides `Equals`, it's not allowed to overload `==`.

However, this same class is used internally in the DLL and, inevitably using LINQ, I find myself writing `.Where(x => x.Id == Ids.House)` which obviously won't work.

One possible solution is to define an `IdInternal` which is internal and can override `==` and then wrap that inside an `Id`.

Without that solution in place (I suspect it would have to happen for several classes), is there any way to warn developers via compile / runtime errors that they should not be using == for this class?

Comment: Overloading (it's not overriding) `==` works for me in VS11 Beta under Win8 CP. What makes you think you can't do that?

Comment: Oops! Thanks for pointing that out. When you switch output type to WinMD you get a restricted subset of the framework. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977010(v=vs.110).aspx#OperatorOverloading for "operating overload not allowed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator overloading is not supported in winmd files.  It's possible that the compilers may have a bug that prevents them from blocking the use of operator overloads in winmd files, but you cannot rely on that behavior.

I think the InternalId and Id may be the best way to go.

Comment: Fair enough - I was hoping there might be a workaround of sorts that wasn't mentioned in the current documentation :) Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea. Say your Id is Int.

Create a new custom type, add explicit conversion to Int operator and mark it with the [Obsolete] attribute with a warning as the result.

Comment: I don't understand, how exactly would that help? Maybe a code sample would be useful.

Comment: I tried implementing it but the new custom type also cannot expose operator overloads in Windows Runtime, so you end up with wrapping an internal type in the public class, which I think is what I was hoping to avoid in the question :)